# Is it possible to use AWS DMS for migrating serverless aurora v2 to rds instance of postgresql?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I have Aurora PostgreSQL serverless DB in AWS. I want to migrate it to RDS instance. The target RDS is also postgresql. I am not sure as I am new to AWS?

Any help would be beneficial for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can use DMS. The documentation shows that Aurora PostgreSQL and RDS PostgreSQL are valid [source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Sources.html)/[targets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Introduction.Targets.html). You can also take a logical dump of your database using a tool like pg_dump and then restoring it to an RDS instance.